# Google Dialer crashes when Contacts are disabled

Tags: contacts, google-apps, xprivacy

I disabled the Google "10003 Contacts" App in the Apps preferences, and although I have installed CardDav for my contacts that I use via my owncloud, the Dialer crashes when I click on a Contact in the call-history

How Can I Block the default Google Contacts app without loosing the functionality in the dialer?

Answer (score 1):

I installed xPrivacy on my rooted device and disallowed the App "10003 Contacts" all privileges but some:

- Contacts->"contacts/contacts"
- ContactsProvider2
- android.intent.action.VIEW

that seems to be the only needed privileges